# usar JAXBElement en weblogic

Tags: xml, weblogic, docx

estoy intentando hacer una conversión de Text a JAXBElement pero me sale error de que no se puede convertir y buscando me sale que webLogic no maneja JAXBElement

el código que estoy utilizando es para remplazar los datos de un Word creado en una plantilla por datos de BD

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(ruta));
            List texts = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w:t", true);
            for (Object obj : texts) {
                Text text = (Text) ((JAXBElement) obj).getValue();
                //text = ((org.docx4j.wml.Text) obj).getValue();
                String textValue = text.getValue();
                for (Object key : mappings.keySet()) {
                    textValue = textValue.replaceAll(key.toString(), (String) mappings.get(key));
                }
                text.setValue(textValue);
            }
```

como podría hacer para que me funcione :c

Comment: Recuerda siempre añadir el mensaje de error exacto (ojalá una traza de error, al menos las primeras veinte líneas o algo) para que no nos digas "sale algo como que falla al hacer X" sino que veamos qué dice el compilador.

Answer (score 1):

pude solucionarlo cambiando la forma en que hacia el for para que no use el JAXBElement y quedo asi:

```
for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); i++) {
    Object text = texts.get(i);
    Text textElement = (Text) text;
    String textValue = textElement.getValue();
    for (Object key : mappings.keySet()) {
        textValue = textValue.replaceAll(key.toString(), (String) mappings.get(key));
    }
    textElement.setValue(textValue);
}
```